# Is there standard ticket data format specification for commercial flight operators?

Tags: air-travel, tickets

I am new to this group and what brings me here is I am doing a research on ticketing solutions for commercial airlines. So I just wanted to find out if there's a international standard specification for data exchange between ticketing solutions and where can I find it *(if it exists)*?

By specification I am referring to data fields and sizes that should be captured on a ticketing system like PNR, departure/destination, datetime & airport, ticket number & cost, no shows, etc

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with travel.

Comment: I agree, and voted to close. But for some guidance to the OP: this question is off-topic because it doesn't address a "practical, answerable [issue] based on actual problems that you face." Conducting research on ticketing solutions for commercial airlines doesn't meet this requirement. You can read more about what's OK here in this Help document: https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, and see what isn't OK in this Help document: https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: In addition to being off-topic, your question is very vague and very broad. What exactly are you trying to achieve? At what level? I.e. between airlines and who else? Airports? Passengers? Ground handling companies? GDS? Travel agents? On the ticketing side a lot of it is probably [GDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_distribution_system)-specific, so you'd have to check what Amadeus, Sabre, and Travelport say. You may also want to check what IATA and possibly ICAO publish. SITA may have quite a few things as they provide the network for many operators.

Comment: @jcaron you have given me good pointers and my apologies for an off topic posting.